# Page Redirect when session end in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to do redirect to login when current session end and that config must be working at any **View** and **Controller**.

**My current code in *Global.asax*:**

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     Session.Abandon();
     //GetPath() is getting currently path
     // eg. http://localhost/mymvcproject
     Response.Redirect(PATH.GetPath() + "User/LogOn");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the following setting under <system.web> in your web.config file:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

then fill the following text in your site.Master

```
if (Session.IsNewSession)
{
    Response.Redirect(PATH.GetPath() + "User/LogOn");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code can work because `Session_End()` is more usually invoked when there is NO request made by the browser after a specific duration.  Therefore, `Response` here would correspond to no particular request, and thus, no redirection.

Instead, try to handle `Application_Start` and check for `Session.IsNew` property.  If it's `true`, then perform the redirection.  (Consider doing that by invoking [`FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirecttologinpage?view=netframework-4.8.1) though.)

When checking for `IsNew`, beware of the situation described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200809143811/http://geekswithblogs.net/dlussier/archive/2008/01/15/118572.aspx).  I guess assigning some dummy session variable during the login process will address that, although I haven't tried myself.